# Why is something for $PS3 shown, even when $PS3 is empty?

Tags: bash, prompt

```
$ echo $PS1
$
$ echo $PS2
>
$ echo $PS3

$ echo $PS4
+
$ select i in 1 2 3
> do
> case $i in
> 1)
> echo 1
> ;;
> *)
> ;;
> esac
> done
1) 1
2) 2
3) 3
#? 1
1
$ PS3="##? "
$ select i in 1 2 3; do case $i in 1) echo 1; ;; *) ;; esac; done
1) 1
2) 2
3) 3
##? 1
1
```

As you can see, `$PS1`, `$PS2` and `$PS4` have a value and work like intended. `$PS3` is empty (or contains a space, tab, etc.), but `select` is using `#?` for `$PS3`, but when the variable is set, it works normally.

Why does this behave this way and why was it designed this way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because the doc says so:

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#Bash-Variables

> PS3
>
> The value of this variable is used as the prompt for the select command. If this variable is not set, the select command prompts with ‘#? ’

Comment: The key here is `If this variable is not set` part. User can try setting it to blank character or space, or maybe even null

Answer (score 11):

It seems to be hard-coded in Bash . In `execute_cmd.c`, function `execute_select_command()`, there's this:

```
ps3_prompt = get_string_value ("PS3");
if (ps3_prompt == 0)
    ps3_prompt = "#? ";
```

Note that it only happens if `PS3` is unset. If you set it to an empty string, `select` will happily prompt you with, well, nothing.

Comment: Can you provide information, why this is designed this way?

Comment: I can only guess that it's so that an empty prompt doesn't happen by accident (since that might be confusing). But I can't know for sure, and that assumption doesn't tell why bash does it by making the unset value a special case, instead of just setting the variable by default.

Answer (score 4):

In `bash`, [`PS3` was set to `"#? "` when not set](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n3150), which is default.

Also, neither `select` nor `PS3` is POSIX defined, so the behavior can be varied:

- `ksh`, `mksh`, `yash`, `zsh` and schily `sh` set default to `"#? "`.
- `dash`, heirloom `sh`, busybox `sh` do not set `PS3`

Comment: Yash 2.39 doesn't have PS3 set

Comment: @Motte001 It does with my 2.9

Comment: I tested it on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

Others have answered why, but here is how - set your PS3 to null :

```
$ PS3=$'\0'
$ select i in 1 2 3; do case $i in 1) echo "option #" 1; ;; *) ;; esac; done
1) 1
2) 2
3) 3
1
option # 1
```

Comment: `PS3=` accomplishes the same thing

Comment: @chepner Why does it accomplish such a thing? It doesn't set it to `"\0"`, it sets it to `""`.

Comment: Because bash is written in C and internally each string in C stored with ending NULL character. There's a question on U&L somewhere with answer by Gilles